# What is the different between :host ,:host() ,:host-context selectors

Tags: css, angular, angular5

I 'm styling an angular component from it 's style file ,I have found that I have to use **:host ,:host()** or **:host-context** selector , What is the different between each of them?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

#### :host

Is syntax for styling the host component.

#### :host(.element)

Is an experimental CSS pseudo-class function that selects `the shadow host of the shadow DOM containing the CSS it is used inside` ([Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:host()))

#### :host-context

Is syntax for styling a specific class anywhere outside the current element. The class must already be applied to an element outside the scope of the current element.

More in-depth info on the context of Angular applications can be found in [this blog post](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-host-context/).

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but from the what I understand (and from what is described on MDN) I don't see how `:host` and `:host-context` are specific only to Angular. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:host

Comment: Yeah you're right, I only ever saw it in the Angular context, corrected the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Base on my observation `:host` apply style for the component,`:host(.class)` apply style for the component if component has the class specified.`:host-context(.class)` apply style for the component if the host component of component has the class specified and if component has the class that also count.

In short, `:host-context` seems search deep for the condition.